# QuestDB installation on a VPS web infrastructure newbie - moving

Tags: python, feed, vps, questdb

I have a fx vol model which I have written in python / questdb on my local machine. The standalone model works as an application in my machine and I also have lots of feeds written which are constantly updating the local machine questdb instance.

Now I want to move to web and have my application and database on the web server away from my machine.

I am not too familiar of web servers and how to install a questdb there.

From my knowledge I will need :

1. a VPS paid subscription where I have centOS and I have python support.
2. I need to install questdb here ( using docker ?)
3. Install all my python model here
4. Start the questdb in the VPS
5. Configure my scripts to use the hosted questdb
6. The model saves output in a table in questdb ; while the scripts also keep on updating new feeds to questdb
7. Start a webserver which provides a web access to the model results saved in the questdb
   7.a I need to provide username and login for the website
   7.b I need to use some vitualization
   7.c I need the users once they are logged in to run some simulations

What I need some quidance is :

1. What sort of VPS service to look for
2. Has any one already installed a questdb in this way
3. Which webserver is the best for python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of good questions there. Will try to help with all of them (disclaimer, I work for QuestDB as a developer advocate)

1. *What sort of VPS service to look for:*

Anything will work, but depending on the volume you are going to ingest/query, you will greatly benefit from a fast drive. In many cases the default disk drive for a VPS/Cloud provider will be slower than the SSD drive on your local development machine. See if the default works for you and otherwise select a better option when starting your virtual machine.

2. *Has any one already installed a questdb in this way*

Sure. If you want to install on AWS, Google Cloud, or Digital Ocean, you have detailed instructions at the [QuestDB site](https://questdb.io/docs/deployment/aws-official-ami/). If you prefer to use Docker, it is fully supported, but a popular option is installing the binaries and just start QuestDB as a service.

3. *Which webserver is the best for python*

This one is tricky, as it really depends on what you will do with it. From your question I am getting the idea you want to run a small user-facing web application that will also run some background jobs. For that scenario a suitable framework can be [Flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/), which also offers some plugins for [user/login management](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and for [background tasks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/celery/) (using redis as a dependency)